# Why does GRE tunnel has lesser TxBS/RxBS than its physical interface?

Tags: routing, tunnel, gre

Given for instance,

```
interface Tunnel200
tunnel destination 110.153.1.1
```

There's a static route for 110.153.1.1, pointing to physical interface Gi0/0.
Gi0/0 is only used for tunnel200.

Under `show interface summary`,

the TxBS/RxBS of tunnel200 is always slightly lower than the physical interface Gi0/0.
Shouldn't it be the other way round as there is overhead for the GRE tunnel?

Comment: The overhead is only visible (and countable) *outside* the tunnel...

Comment: @Zac67 oh thanks for clarifying! Is there a reason why the TxBS/RxBS is always slightly lower for the tunnel rather than equal to the physical interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(from comment) The overhead is only visible (and countable) *outside* the tunnel. Roughly you should see *(outer packet header + GRE header) * number of packets* more traffic on the outside (physical) interface than on the tunnel interface.

Depending on *where* you're watching, a physical interface might also be counting L2 traffic (add the L2 header size * number of packets), and additionally might be receiving non-tunnel traffic (CDP/LLDP, BPDUs, OSPF, ...) - low-volume unless the interface has more uses.